# In matlab, conv2(M,N,'valid') with similar sizes of M and N

Tags: matlab

Let :

```
[220, 220] = size(M); and [208, 208] = size(N).
```

The following command takes `~0.025s`

```
 tic;C = conv2(M,N,'valid');toc

[13,13]=size(C);
```

I want to faster it. So I downloads some code from Internet which named Conv_fast and so on.

But I tested some including using FFT. They are not faster than `0.025s`. Some take `0.2s`.

So is there any possible way to faster it?

As mentioned above, I tried the following function,

```
function g = conv2FFT(h, f)

% g = conv2FFT(h, f)
%
% DESC:
% computes the 2D convolution via FFT
%
% AUTHOR
% Marco Zuliani - zuliani@ece.ucsb.edu
%
% VERSION:
% 1.0.0
%
% INPUT:
% h                 = convolution kernel
% f                 = input signal
%
% OUTPUT:
% g                 = output signal
%
% HISTORY
% 1.0.0             ??/??/07 Initial version

sh = size(h);
sf = size(f);

% zero pad the input signals
fm = zeros(sf+2*(sh-1), class(f));
o = sh-1;
fm( o(1)+(1:size(f,1)), o(2)+(1:size(f,2)) ) = f;

h_zp = zeros(size(fm), class(h));
h_zp(1:size(h,1), 1:size(h,2)) = h;

% compute the convolution in frequency
F = fft2(fm);
H = fft2(h_zp);
Y = F.*H;

% back to spatial domain
g = real( ifft2(Y) );

% remove padding
o = floor(1.5*size(h))-1;
g = g( o(1)+(1:size(f,1)), o(2)+(1:size(f,2)) );

return
```

But it takes ~0.1 sec.

Now I use c++ to do this job. It is not what I want. But it is a little faster. It takes 0.015s.

Here is my code. I have a problem about using `omp.h`. Because no matter I use `omp.h` or not, the running time is similar. So `omp.h` did not faster the code. And I have more than 1 cpu.
Do anyone know the reason?

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<omp.h>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// compile with: mex CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -fopenmp" LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS -fopenmp" mex_convolution.cpp
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// entry function
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
    double *input,*output,*filter;
        int I_row,I_col,filter_rown,nRow,filter_coln,nCol,N;

        input = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
        I_row = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
        I_col = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

        filter = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
        filter_rown = mxGetM(prhs[1]);
        filter_coln = mxGetN(prhs[1]);
        nRow = I_row-filter_rown+1;
        nCol = I_col-filter_coln+1;
        plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nRow,nCol,mxREAL);
        output = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

        //handle central region
        int col,row;
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (col = 0; col < nCol; col++)
        {
                #pragma omp parallel for
                for (row = 0; row < nRow; row++)
                {
                        int idx = 0;
                        int idx_col,idx_row;
                        double response = 0;


                        #pragma omp parallel for
                        for (int filter_col = 0; filter_col<filter_coln; filter_col++)
                        {
                              #pragma omp parallel for
                                for (int filter_row = 0; filter_row<filter_rown; filter_row++)
                                {
                                        idx_col = col + filter_col;
                                        idx_row = row + filter_row;
                                        response = response + input[idx_row + idx_col*I_row] * filter[idx];
                                        idx++;
                                }
                        }
                        output[row + col*nRow] = response;
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: Is the kernel separable? That can speed things

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, it is not separable.

Comment: 0.2 seconds is pretty fast IMHO.... especially if you're using MATLAB.  Unfortunately, this is as fast as you're going to get it as it uses the FFT for convolution.  Did you try using `imfilter` from the Image Processing Toolbox?  That uses Intel Performance Primitives to speed up filtering and other image processing related tasks.

Comment: Before I tried imfilter and conv2 are almost same.